# Maximum Volume Ring in Android

Tags: android

I want change volume of android alarm (STREAM_RING).

I try this:

```
audioManager.adjustStreamVolume(
   AudioManager.STREAM_RING,
   audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING),
   AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND
);
```

But it doesn't work and i have error(Bad direction 7)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use setStreamVolume not adjustStreamVolume. AdjustStreamVolume is to adjust 1 level higher or lower.

```
audioManager.setStreamVolume(
   AudioManager.STREAM_RING,
   audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING),
   AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [the documentation of AudioManager.adjustStreamVolume](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#adjustStreamVolume%28int,%20int,%20int%29):

> **public void adjustStreamVolume (int streamType, int direction, int flags)**
>
> ...
>
> *direction*   The direction to adjust the volume. One of ADJUST_LOWER, ADJUST_RAISE, or ADJUST_SAME.

Your second parameter is none of these three values. Maybe you wanted to use [setStreamValue](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#setStreamVolume%28int,%20int,%20int%29) instead?